# 'Correct' term for... upwards moving menu?

Tags: terminology

I posted a (technically inclined) question at StackOverflow — and I agree with a particular commentary, and we'd like to get your opinion. Here's my original question:

> Dropdown menu.
>
> But ours open upward - 'popup', as in
>   'popup menu' has proved oddly
>   confusing to some of our business
>   oriented folk. So we tried throwing in
>   'vertical menu' and then.. this was a
>   mistake.. 'vertical animating menu'..
>   so what would you call it?

And here's the [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449240) for our commentary. It'll be interesting to see what you all can come up with!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a "flyout" menu, which is basically what the Start button has.  You click an item, a menu flies out in some direction from that item.

Comment: Ok, checking this as the 'correct' answer, for its more generic application - though I do like 'rising menu' :)

Answer (score 4):

As it doesn't seem like there is already a terminology, the simplest route would be to use the antonym of dropdown: "*riseup menu*". However it sounds a bit clunky, maybe because it is a neologism.

**EDIT:** I initialy proposed *uprise* instead of *riseup* but as @Tomalak pointed, not only *riseup* is in fact analoguous to *dropdown*, but also *uprise* would have a completely different meaning.

Comment: Analoguous to "dropdown" would be "riseup". Easier to pronounce, IMHO.

Comment: @Tomalak, yeah you are right, I brainfarted.

Comment: Buildling on that, maybe just 'rising menu' would sound less awkward?

Comment: Bingo, I like that one - 'rising menu'. I'll share that just now, many thanks, but any more suggestions also welcome!

Comment: I think Benjol should add his suggestion as an answer - it's certainly the one I would endorse.